# How do you prove that every vector enclosed in a space has a unique linear combination made from the basis of the space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let's say there's a vector $\mathbf{v}$ in space $\mathbf{V}$, and the basis for $\mathbf{V}$ is given by $\mathbf{S}=\{v_1, v_2, ... v_n\}$.

I start out with an equation $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$. I let $\mathbf{x}$ equal the unique combination, $\mathbf{b}$ equal the vector $\mathbf{v}$, and $A$ be the matrix with columns $v_1, v_2, ... v_n$.

I started out by saying $\mathbf{S}$ is an independent set so, the rank of $\mathbf{A}$ must equal $n$. I'm not sure how I should prove the rank of $A_\mathbf{b}$ is also $n$. Rouche's theorem states that the augmented matrix $A_\mathbf{b}$ has the same rank as  $\mathbf{A}$ if there is only one solution $\mathbf{x}$ for the equation $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$.

Comment: How do you want to prove this with the consistency theorem?
Do you really mean
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConsistencyTheorem.html
this one?

Comment: The consistency theorem says the for a matrix in Gauss-jordan form, if the rank of A equals the rank of Ab, then there is a unique solution. In other words showing that the ranks are equal will show that there is only one combination for any vector v.

Comment: Here's a link for what I thought was the consistency theorem:  http://mathumatiks.com/index.php?module=subpage&nid=267

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already know that $\text{rank}(A)=n$. But now we are ready: The rank of $A|b$ is also $n$ because $A|b$ has as many rows as your matrix $A$.
Remember that your theorem doesn't say to determine the rank of $A \cdot b$ but of $A|b$, so it's pretty easy because the rank of $A | b$ can't get greater or smaller.

Comment: I think I get it... thanks.